# Unable to modify file on task scheduler execution using account NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Tags: c#, permissions, taskscheduler

I have an xml file which is to be modified from task scheduler .exe configured.
Task scheduler runs without any error but file is not updated. I tried to log every step to see if any exception is occurring but found none.

I think this has something to do with permissions but not sure what am i missing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you run the exe you've scheduled directly, does it work as expected?

Comment: If i run .exe directly then it does work. And when i install the same in my system and execute it then it works fine. Also, it works perfectly when i execute in debug mode

Comment: 1. try to make the folder and the file accessible to "everyone"
If this is working it is a permission problem

2. how often is this task running? Maybe the task before is still working on that file

Comment: I have already tried with "everyone" it does not work and task runs daily once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

Issue was with the path of xml file to be saved.
What i wrote was config.Save("File.xml");
This did not work. Then i hardcoded the complete path and it worked.

So, instead of using only filename or Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase) + @"\File.xml", i used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//" + "File.xml" and worked perfectly.